# how can i display value for visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

this is my source code for visualization to bar plot. and i plot by my data. but i need to make a display about value.

But i don't have any idea. how can i do it?

```
bar_width = 0.4
alpha = 0.5

value_dic = visualization_missing(df_train)

value_data = []
label_data = []
count = 5

for i in range (count):
    value_data.append(value_dic[i][0])
    label_data.append(value_dic[i][1])

index = np.arange(count)
    
p_train = plt.bar(index , value_data , bar_width, color = 'b', alpha = alpha , label = 'Train')

# get number of count missing value in test set by features
value_dic_test = visualization_missing(df_test)

value_data_test = []
label_data_test = []
count = 5

for i in range (count):
    value_data_test.append(value_dic[i][0])
    label_data_test.append(value_dic[i][1])

index = np.arange(count)

p_test = plt.bar(index + bar_width , value_data_test , bar_width , color = 'r' , alpha = alpha , label = 'Test')

#visualization numebr of train,test missing value 
plt.title = ('Missing Value in Train set & Test set')
plt.ylabe = ("Number of missing value")
plt.xlabe = ("Feature")
plt.xticks(index, label_data, fontsize = 10)
plt.legend((p_train[0], p_test[0]),('Training','Test'), fontsize = 10)

    
plt.show()
```

and then the dataset for visualization.

```
[(1456, 'PoolQC'),
 (1408, 'MiscFeature'),
 (1352, 'Alley'),
 (1169, 'Fence'),
 (730, 'FireplaceQu'),
 (227, 'LotFrontage'),
 (78, 'GarageCond'),
 (76, 'GarageType'),
 (45, 'BsmtCond'),
 (44, 'BsmtExposure'),
 (42, 'BsmtFinType2'),
 (16, 'MasVnrType'),
 (15, 'MasVnrArea'),
 (4, 'MSZoning'),
 (2, 'Functional'),
 (1, 'SaleType')]
```

how can i display the value on the bar chart?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice example in the [gallery of matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) where the returned coordinates of the bar chart are used to annotate the bar plot:

```
def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

p_test = plt.bar(index + bar_width , value_data_test , [...])
autolabel(p_test)
```